# Is there are way to stop the property grid from catching exceptions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, propertygrid

I am getting a cross thread exception when using a property grid to modify a property of a control in my application.  I have tried to use the Exceptions dialog in Visual Studio to break on all exceptions (I selected all check boxes in the dialog).  The property grid still catches the exception on it's own so I can't break to find the code that is causing the issue.  Is there a way to break on the property grid exceptions?

Comment: You can configure Visual Studio to stop on all exception, including 1st chance ones. Check out what returns this google query: http://www.google.com/search?q=configure+visual+studio+to+breal+on+first+chance+exceptions+&meta=

Comment: Thank you.  By following a couple of links I found out that there is a debugging option under General called "Just my code".  I turned this off and was able to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is the exception being thrown at design-time? I assume this is the case because you're talking about the property grid. If so, you won't be able to catch it with the same instance of Visual Studio in which the designer is running. To debug design-time behavior of controls, you need to attach a second instance of Visual Studio to the instance that is running the designer - then that second instance should break when the exception is thrown. You can choose *Attach to Process* from the *Debug* menu and select *devenv.exe* for the process (make sure you pick the right instance of *devenv.exe*!).

Comment: Sorry, this is occurring at run-time. I am using the property grid control on one of my forms.  It is catching the exception so I can't pin point the issue.